# In a tree data structure, is a node a sibling of itself?

Tags: data-structures, tree, siblings

I am building a tree like data structure.  What is the expected behavior if I have a method

```
public Set getSiblingNodes(Node node);
```

Should this method return a set including or excluding itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider yourself as your own brother/sister?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It should contain only it's siblings.
**A node is not a sibling of itself**.
(Why would you think otherwise?)

Comment: The formal definition of sibling is "If node x and node y share the same parent node, they are siblings".  If x and y are the same node, that statement still holds true.  I agree with you, however.

Answer (score 0):

generally **no**, 
**But** you can define some sort of tree, where siblings build the circular list and then if this list has one node it will be a sibling of itself.